# I am overridding the default file in my module,but when i add extra method in the file my overriden is not called

Tags: magento2, overrides, interface

I am overridding the default file in my module,it fine but when i add extra method in the overriden file the method is not called.

these is my di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectM‌​anager/etc/config.xs‌​d"> 
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type=Silk/Helloworld\Model\Category" />
</config>
```

default path:

Magento/Catalog/Model/Category.php

in my module file path:

Silk/Helloworld/Model/Category.php

in Category.php if i add extra method it is not called any idea how to make this work.

```
<?php

namespace Silk\Helloworld\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Convert\ConvertArray;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Profiler;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;

class Category extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface,
    \Silk\Helloworld\Api\Data\CategoryInterface,
    \Silk\Helloworld\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface
{
    /**
     * Entity code.
     * Can be used as part of method name for entity processing
     */
    const ENTITY = 'catalog_category';

    /**#@+
     * Category display modes
     */
    const DM_PRODUCT = 'PRODUCTS';

    const DM_PAGE = 'PAGE';

    const DM_MIXED = 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE';
    /**#@-*/

    /**
     * Id of root category
     */
    const ROOT_CATEGORY_ID = 0;

    /**
     * Id of category tree root
     */
    const TREE_ROOT_ID = 1;

    const CACHE_TAG = 'cat_c';

    /**#@+
     * Constants
     */
    const KEY_PARENT_ID = 'parent_id';
    const KEY_NAME = 'name';
    const KEY_PARENTLEVELNAME = 'parentlevelname';
    const KEY_IS_ACTIVE = 'is_active';
    const KEY_POSITION = 'position';
    const KEY_LEVEL = 'level';
    const KEY_UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
    const KEY_CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const KEY_PATH = 'path';
    const KEY_AVAILABLE_SORT_BY = 'available_sort_by';
    const KEY_INCLUDE_IN_MENU = 'include_in_menu';
    const KEY_PRODUCT_COUNT = 'product_count';
    const KEY_CHILDREN_DATA = 'children_data';
    /**#@-*/

    /**#@-*/
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'catalog_category';

    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'category';

    /**
     * Model cache tag for clear cache in after save and after delete
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_cacheTag = self::CACHE_TAG;

    /**
     * URL Model instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * URL rewrite model
     *
     * @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite
     * @deprecated 101.1.0
     */
    protected $_urlRewrite;

    /**
     * Use flat resource model flag
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_useFlatResource = false;

    /**
     * Category design attributes
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $_designAttributes = [
        'custom_design',
        'custom_design_from',
        'custom_design_to',
        'page_layout',
        'custom_layout_update',
        'custom_apply_to_products',
    ];

    /**
     * Attributes are that part of interface
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $interfaceAttributes = [
        'id',
        self::KEY_PARENT_ID,
        self::KEY_NAME,
        self::KEY_PARENTLEVELNAME,
        self::KEY_IS_ACTIVE,
        self::KEY_POSITION,
        self::KEY_LEVEL,
        self::KEY_UPDATED_AT,
        self::KEY_CREATED_AT,
        self::KEY_AVAILABLE_SORT_BY,
        self::KEY_INCLUDE_IN_MENU,
        self::KEY_CHILDREN_DATA,
    ];

    /**
     * Category tree model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Tree
     */
    protected $_treeModel = null;

    /**
     * Core data
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * Catalog config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_catalogConfig;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Store collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_storeCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Category tree factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\TreeFactory
     */
    protected $_categoryTreeFactory;

    /**
     * @var Indexer\Category\Flat\State
     */
    protected $flatState;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator
     */
    protected $categoryUrlPathGenerator;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface
     */
    protected $urlFinder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry
     */
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\MetadataServiceInterface
     */
    protected $metadataService;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryAttributeRepositoryInterface $metadataService,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Tree $categoryTreeResource,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\TreeFactory $categoryTreeFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory $storeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filter,
        Indexer\Category\Flat\State $flatState,
        \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder,
        \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->metadataService = $metadataService;
        $this->_treeModel = $categoryTreeResource;
        $this->_categoryTreeFactory = $categoryTreeFactory;
        $this->_storeCollectionFactory = $storeCollectionFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->flatState = $flatState;
        $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator = $categoryUrlPathGenerator;
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
        );
    }
 public function getAddName()
    {
        return $this->_getData(self::KEY_PARENTLEVELNAME);
        //return 'hello';
    }

    public function setAddName($addname)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_PARENTLEVELNAME, $addname);
    }

    }
    ?>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your di.xml file code for override model.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type=Silk/Helloworld\Model\Category" /></config>

Comment: I have added my di.xml @SureshChikani

Comment: show your di.xml code here in que.

Comment: I have updated my question please check @RonakChauhan

Comment: Oh man! you have to copy all methods from Core Category.php which are implimented from interface.

Comment: i have all the method but to show you i have only kept those method which i have added custom @RonakChauhan

Comment: have you checked wheather your class is being called or not?

Comment: Yup it is calling when i put some return with static value from my module category file, but when it comes to new add methods those are not calling @RonakChauhan

Comment: Put Data API into your module and give your defination into that .

Comment: I have overriden those categoryInterface file in my module but no use.@RonakChauhan

Comment: @RonakChauhan. actually the overridden class is not calling. Do you give any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace this di.xml with yours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectM‌​anager/etc/config.xs‌​d"> 
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="Silk/Helloworld\Model\Category" />
</config>
```

To override Cateogry.php class you have to put all methods of interface into your  Category.php class and you may put constructor also and send all required parameters with parent().

> > NOTE: Impliment interface into your Class also. All interface methods are Abstract methods, So you have to override or give defination into your class.

Comment: One more thing @pranay, You missed to start " in your preference type.

Comment: I have overriden those interface methods in my module interface and defined those methods in category.php but those methods aren't called @RonakChauhan

Comment: Update your category.php in que.

Comment: added please check @Ronak Chauhan

Comment: Has i made mistake in files overriding. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace below code to `di.xml` file

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="Silk\Helloworld\Model\Category" />
```

Comment: I already have that code in my di.xml

Comment: But i have interface that uses category.php

Comment: please clear you issue.